# Protect a url with HTTP authentication based on query string parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-authentication

I have a site with links like this:

> http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1
>
> http://www.example.com/index.php?id=3

etc.

I would like to have htaccess password protection for a specific ID, say 200.

How can I do this?

Comment: What kind of protection? 403 Forbidden error?

Comment: No, just show the htaccess user and pass popup.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: I have provided an answer on how to do it in .htaccess itself.

Comment: +1 There's very little htaccess can't do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not straight forward but here is a way it can be done in `.htaccess` itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

# set URI to /index.php/200 if query string is id=200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(200|1)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/?$ $1/%1 [NC]

# set SECURED var to 1 if URI is /index.php/200
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/index\.php/(200|1)" SECURED

# enforce auth if SECURED=1
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Thanks @RaviThapliyal: I learnt some new tricks while answering this nice question, very interesting.

Comment: How could this be changed to work also on links like http://www.example.com/index.php/?id=1 ? Notice the slash before the query string. Thanks.

Comment: do you think it would be possible to have this working for two different IDs, each having a separate .htpasswd file?

Comment: That is also possible but little more code and some work arounds. I request opening a new question for that since that will change nature of this question entirely.

Answer (score 5):

You're not going to be able to use htaccess to do this. There's a way to require authorization based on an environment variable, but you can't match against the query string using a `SetEnvIf` and mod_rewrite's `RewriteCond` happens after the auth module so even if you match against it, the auth will already have been bypassed.

You need to implement this specifically in your `index.php`. There's some build-ins in php [that does some of this for you](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). So something like:

```
if($_GET['id'] == "200") {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
        exit;
    } else {
        // check username/password here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, +1 for the PHP features I didn't know about, but I need htaccess solution.