# How to protect some URLs with HTTP authentication using a regex?

Tags: regex, apache, http-authentication

I have a public website with an admin area. So I want to protect this admin area using HTTP authentication.

The admin area has this URL: `http://mypublicwebsite.com/myadminarea/`

`myadminarea`is **not** a physical directory on my server, there's a routing system based on the requested URL.

Is there an easy way to define that every URL that matches `http://mypublicwebsite.com/myadminarea/*` must use http authentication?

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500010/354578), but it seems too complicated to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found a solution using the [`LocationMatch` apache directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/core.html#locationmatch), to be added in my virtualhost definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ...

    <LocationMatch "/myadminarea/.*">
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "Login Required"
        AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
        Require valid-user
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it using `mod_setenvif` and `mod_auth`. Place this code in your root .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/myadminarea" SECURED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
Satisfy any
```

**PS:** Make sure you create passwords as per Apache manual instructions.

Comment: I've juste found the `LocationMatch` apache directive, it seems to be a nice solution too.

Comment: `Location` directive works but that cannot work in `.htaccess`, it has to be placed in Apache server config.

Comment: Indeed, but I have access to my vhost config, that's not a problem to me.