# Bypassing AuthType with url parameter in Request_URI using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

Based on this question I build a protection for

I want to bypass the Authorization with user and password by AuthType when the URI contains a parameter value. If the parameter is not set or wrong the usual user/pw input should be necessary.
Ex:
www.domain.com?id=200 -> NO password required
www.domain.com -> password required

I found this question. It works fine. But I'm not able to change behavior:
[Protect a url with HTTP authentication based on query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491680/protect-a-url-with-http-authentication-based-on-query-string-parameter)

The following code doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On

# set URI to /index.php/200 if query string is id=200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(200|1)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/?$ $1/%1 [NC]

# set SECURED var to 1 if URI is /index.php/200
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/index\.php/(200|1)" SECURED

# enforce auth if SECURED=1
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from env=SECURED
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /register noauth=1
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Auth"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
<RequireAny>
    Require env noauth
    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html